# How To Make A Timer That Counts Time at a Factor of Real Time in Python?

Tags: python, time

This code makes a little stopwatch popup on your screen.
I did some copying a pasting to get a second counter.
I'm trying to get the second counter to count at a slower amount of time than the real time the counter makes.
Like for every 1 minutes that elapses in the top counter 15 seconds elapses in the second counter.
I've tried putting a * 0.25 everywhere but haven't gotten it.

```
from Tkinter import *
import time

class StopWatch(Frame):  
    """ Implements a stop watch frame widget. """                                                                
    def __init__(self, parent=None, **kw):        
        Frame.__init__(self, parent, kw)
        self._start = 0.0        
        self._elapsedtime = 0.0
        self._running = 0
        self.timestr = StringVar()               
        self.makeWidgets()
        self.makeWidgets2()

    def makeWidgets(self):                         
        """ Make the time label. """
        l = Label(self, textvariable=self.timestr)
        self._setTime(self._elapsedtime)
        l.pack(fill=X, expand=NO, pady=2, padx=2)                      

    def makeWidgets2(self):                         
        """ Make the time label. """
        l = Label(self, textvariable=self.timestr)
        self._setTime(self._elapsedtime)
        l.pack(fill=X, expand=NO, pady=2, padx=2)    

    def _update(self): 
        """ Update the label with elapsed time. """
        self._elapsedtime = time.time() - self._start
        self._setTime(self._elapsedtime)
        self._elapsedtime = (self._elapsedtime * 0.1)
        self._timer = self.after(50, self._update)


    def _setTime(self, elap):
        """ Set the time string to Minutes:Seconds:Hundreths """
        minutes = int(elap/60)
        seconds = int(elap - minutes*60.0)
        hseconds = int((elap - minutes*60.0 - seconds)*100)                
        self.timestr.set('%02d:%02d:%02d' % (minutes, seconds, hseconds))

    def Start(self):                                                     
        """ Start the stopwatch, ignore if running. """
        if not self._running:
            ''' make self.start the time now - zero'''
            self._start = time.time() - self._elapsedtime
            self._update()
            self._running = 1

    def Stop(self):                                    
        """ Stop the stopwatch, ignore if stopped. """
        if self._running:
            self.after_cancel(self._timer)            
            self._elapsedtime = time.time() - self._start    
            self._setTime(self._elapsedtime)
            self._running = 0

    def Reset(self):                                  
        """ Reset the stopwatch. """
        self._start = time.time()         
        self._elapsedtime = 0.0    
        self._setTime(self._elapsedtime)


def main():
    root = Tk()
    sw = StopWatch(root)
    sw.pack(side=TOP)

    Button(root, text='Start', command=sw.Start).pack(side=LEFT)
    Button(root, text='Stop', command=sw.Stop).pack(side=LEFT)
    Button(root, text='Reset', command=sw.Reset).pack(side=LEFT)
    Button(root, text='Quit', command=root.quit).pack(side=LEFT)

    root.mainloop()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: dividing seconds by 4 should solve your issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need two have to separate time strings and update them separately. For example in your __init__ function you can define:

```
self.timestr = StringVar()
self.timestr2 = StringVar()
```

and then you can update them seperately in *Start* and also pass a rate parameter for scaling time:

```
self._update(self.timestr, 1.0)
self._update(self.timestr2, 0.5)
```

Here's a full working example:

```
from Tkinter import *
import time

class StopWatch(Frame):
    """ Implements a stop watch frame widget. """
    def __init__(self, parent=None, **kw):
        Frame.__init__(self, parent, kw)
        self._start = 0.0
        self._elapsedtime = 0.0
        self._running = 0
        self.timestr = StringVar()
        self.timestr2 = StringVar()
        self.makeWidgets()
        self.makeWidgets2()

    def makeWidgets(self):
        """ Make the time label. """
        l = Label(self, textvariable=self.timestr)
        self._setTime(self._elapsedtime, self.timestr)
        l.pack(fill=X, expand=NO, pady=2, padx=2)

    def makeWidgets2(self):
        """ Make the time label. """
        l = Label(self, textvariable=self.timestr2)
        self._setTime(self._elapsedtime, self.timestr2)
        l.pack(fill=X, expand=NO, pady=2, padx=2)

    def _update(self, string_obj, rate):
        """ Update the label with elapsed time. """
        self._elapsedtime = time.time() - self._start
        self._setTime(self._elapsedtime*rate, string_obj)
        self._timer = self.after(50, self._update, string_obj, rate)


    def _setTime(self, elap, string_obj):
        """ Set the time string to Minutes:Seconds:Hundreths """
        minutes = int(elap/60)
        seconds = int(elap - minutes*60.0)
        hseconds = int((elap - minutes*60.0 - seconds)*100)
        string_obj.set('%02d:%02d:%02d' % (minutes, seconds, hseconds))

    def Start(self):
        """ Start the stopwatch, ignore if running. """
        if not self._running:
            ''' make self.start the time now - zero'''
            self._start = time.time() - self._elapsedtime
            self._update(self.timestr, 1.0)
            self._update(self.timestr2, 0.5)
            self._running = 1

    def Stop(self):
        """ Stop the stopwatch, ignore if stopped. """
        if self._running:
            self.after_cancel(self._timer)
            self._elapsedtime = time.time() - self._start
            self._setTime(self._elapsedtime)
            self._running = 0

    def Reset(self):
        """ Reset the stopwatch. """
        self._start = time.time()
        self._elapsedtime = 0.0
        self._setTime(self._elapsedtime)


def main():
    root = Tk()
    sw = StopWatch(root)
    sw.pack(side=TOP)

    Button(root, text='Start', command=sw.Start).pack(side=LEFT)
    Button(root, text='Stop', command=sw.Stop).pack(side=LEFT)
    Button(root, text='Reset', command=sw.Reset).pack(side=LEFT)
    Button(root, text='Quit', command=root.quit).pack(side=LEFT)

    root.mainloop()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: Thank you. Though the stop and reset buttons don't work with this new feature. It also can't start again when stopped. I'll work it out myself if you don't feel like it. Best answer regardless.